# Can a bootable NetBSD be built on OSX?

Tags: kernel, osx, make, netbsd

I've got OSX 10.9.5 . I want to build NetBSD (or at least it's kernel) on my OSX box. I've tried building the 'config' program but I can't find 'build.sh'. Is this possible and what would be the steps to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NetBSD has documentation here: [Part V. Building the system](https://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/part-compile.html)

You *might* be able to compile a NetBSD kernel on OSX.  At a minimum, you would need

- the [kernel source tree](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/sys/?only_with_tag=MAIN), i.e., `/sys` (which at least does not conflict with OSX's system directories).
- *whatever* tools are needed, you probably have to download source and compile *those*.  `build.sh` is only a small part of that.

But to the extent that it used the OSX header-files, it may/may not even compile.  You might consider cross-compiling:

- [Chapter 31. Crosscompiling NetBSD with build.sh](https://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-build.html)